# Alternative way for getting the roots of a transcendental equation and verifying them

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear, testing-and-verification

I have the following transcendental equation:

$$2 \cot(x)=\frac{kx}{h(L/N)}-\frac{h(L/N)}{kx}$$

I use the following code to solve it

```
roots = 
  Sort[x /. 
    NSolve[
      {2*Cot[x] == Rationalize[k/(h (L/N))] x - Rationalize[h (L/N)/k]/x, 60 > x > 0}, 
      x, Reals]]
```

Typical values for the constants are $L=0.25,N=20,k=16,h=0.1$:

Is there an alternative way to solve this equation and check whether the answers from both the methods match?

---

```
FindInstance[2*Cot[x] == (k x)/(h (L/Nd)) - h (L/Nd)/(k x), {x}, Reals, 10]
```

leads to

> ```
> {{x -> -0.0124999}, {x -> -0.0124999}, {x -> 0.0124999}, {x -> 0.0124999}, 
> {x -> 0.0124999}, {x -> -0.0124999}, {x -> -0.0124999}, {x -> 0.0124999}, 
> {x -> -0.0124999}, {x -> 0.0124999}}
> ```

Comment: [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)

Comment: @LouisB I tried `FindInstance` but it manages to find only one root. This root matches with the`NSolve`  result. Is there a workaround to this ? Like if I only want positive roots. Giving the argument to `FindInstance` for 10 roots leads to repeated roots. I have added my attempt to the original question.

Comment: Try it this way  `FindInstance[ { 2*Cot[x] == k/(h (L/Nd)) x - h (L/Nd)/k/x, 
  60 > x > 0 }, x, Reals, 30]`

Comment: @LouisB Thanks. It works perfectly. If you can add this as an answer, I am willing to accept it. It solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

roots[Lv_?NumericQ, nv_?NumericQ, kv_?NumericQ, hv_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{L, n, k, h},
  {L, n, k, h} = Rationalize[{Lv, nv, kv, hv}, 0]; Solve[{
    2*Cot[x] == k/(h (L/n)) x - h (L/n)/k/x,
    60 > x > 0}, x, Reals]]
```

The exact solutions are [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects

```
sol1 = roots[0.25, 20, 16, 0.1]
```

[image]

These are approximately

```
sol1 // N

(* {{x -> 0.0124999}, {x -> 3.14164}, {x -> 6.28321}, {x -> 9.42479}, {x -> 
   12.5664}, {x -> 15.708}, {x -> 18.8496}, {x -> 21.9912}, {x -> 
   25.1327}, {x -> 28.2743}, {x -> 31.4159}, {x -> 34.5575}, {x -> 
   37.6991}, {x -> 40.8407}, {x -> 43.9823}, {x -> 47.1239}, {x -> 
   50.2655}, {x -> 53.4071}, {x -> 56.5487}, {x -> 59.6903}} *)
```

You can verify the solutions by substituting back into the equations

```
2*Cot[x] == k/(h (L/n)) x - h (L/n)/k/x &&
    60 > x > 0 /. 
   Thread[{L, n, k, h} ->
     Rationalize[{0.25, 20, 16, 0.1}]] /.
  sol1 // FullSimplify

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, \
True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Using [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) as the second method

```
roots2[Lv_?NumericQ, nv_?NumericQ, kv_?NumericQ, hv_?NumericQ, 
  nmbr_Integer?Positive] := Module[{L, n, k, h},
  {L, n, k, h} = Rationalize[{Lv, nv, kv, hv}, 0];
  FindInstance[
   2*Cot[x] == k/(h (L/n)) x - h (L/n)/k/x &&
    60 > x > 0, x, Reals, nmbr]]

sol2 = roots2[0.25, 20, 16, 0.1, Length[sol1]];
```

Verifying that the exact solutions are identical

```
sol1 === sol2

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very descriptive.

Answer (score 4):

Your equation might be transformed to `2 Cot[x] == x/p - p/x` with a new parameter `p= (h (L/n) )/k`

With

```
p0=(h (L/n) )/k /. {L -> 0.25, n -> 20, k -> 16, h -> 0.1};
(*0.000078125*)
```

you might visualize the solution with `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[ContourPlot[1/(2 Cot[x]) == 1/((x/p) - p/x), {x, 0, 60}, {p, 0, 2 p0},FrameLabel -> {x,"p=\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\(h\)\(\\\ \)\((L/n)\)\(\\\ \)\), \\(k\)]\)"}], {x, 0, .01 Pi /2}, {p, 0, 2 p0}, 
FrameLabel -> {x,"p=\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\(h\)\(\\\ \)\((L/n)\)\(\\\ \)\), \\(k\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

The solution for given `p=p0`follow to

```
NSolve[{2 Cot[x] == x/p0 - p0/x, 0 < x < 60}, x, Reals]
(*{{x -> 0.0124999}, {x -> 3.14164}, {x -> 6.28321}, {x ->9.42479}, {x -> 12.5664}, {x -> 15.708}, {x -> 18.8496}, {x ->21.9912}, {x -> 25.1327}, {x -> 28.2743}, {x -> 31.4159}, {x ->34.5575}, {x -> 37.6991}, {x -> 40.8407}, {x -> 43.9823}, {x ->47.1239}, {x -> 50.2655}, {x -> 53.4071}, {x -> 56.5487}, {x ->59.6903}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the visualizations. I was already using `NSolve` to find the roots and was looking for an alternative.